# Linq-to-SQL in ASP.NET MVC using stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I'm new to Linq-to-SQL and ASP.NET MVC.

Is there any way to use stored procedures in Linq-to-SQL using ASP.NET MVC?

OR is it feasible to use stored procedures with LINQ in ASP.NET MVC?

I want to use CTE inside my stored procedures.

Please give your suggestions to achieve this.

Or better use Entity Framework for it?

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation or a pseudo code example of what you are aiming to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this. You need a model that represents the returned SQL data, in this example I've called it `mySqlModel`.

```
public List<mySqlModel> GetFromStoredProc(int Id)
{
    var returnModel = new List<mySqlModel>();

    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.MyStoredProc";

        var sParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
        sParam.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        sParam.ParameterName = "@Id";
        sParam.Value = Id;
        sParam.IsNullable = false;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(sParam);

        try
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //  return list as ObjectList
            var results = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<mySqlModel>(reader);
            //  cast to List<entity>
            returnModel = (from s in results select s).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex, HttpContext.Current);
        }
        finally
        {
           db.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
    return returnModel;
 }
```

Comment: Ok thank you Sir. I will try and update you with the Same @markpsmith .. :)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the original question - please create another question for it. Also, you don't need to call anyone 'Sir'. Well, not here anyway.

Comment: Sorry was confused in the two questions i have asked..

btw thank you this Code worked fine for me.

Comment: ok, glad to hear it. Please mark the answer as correct if it answered your question.